# ggplot2 Missing y-axis labels

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot, axis-labels

Morning,  I have a little problem with my `ggplot` graph.

For some reason, I can't see right now, the y axis ticks and numbers are missing. Maybe, I'm missing something really obvious here or it's something in my settings.
The toothgrowth dataset does not really fit the graph, but you can still see the problem (normally `facet_wrap` is included, but it does not work with this dataset).

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggbeeswarm)
library(gghalves)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)

theme_set(theme_bw(16))

data <- ToothGrowth

a<- ggplot(data, aes(x=supp, y=len)) +
geom_half_boxplot(
data = data %>% filter(supp=="OJ"), 
aes(x = supp, y = len,  fill=supp), outlier.color = NA) +
scale_fill_manual(values=c("#F2F2F2", "#999999"))+

geom_half_boxplot(
data = data %>% filter(supp=="VC"), 
aes(x = supp, y = len, fill=supp), side = "r", outlier.color = NA) +

geom_line(aes(group=supp, colour = supp), position = position_dodge(0.2), alpha = 0.3) +
geom_point(aes(group=supp, colour = supp),size=1,shape=21, position = position_dodge(0.2)) +
scale_color_manual(values=c("chartreuse3", "yellow2",
                          "firebrick3"))+
#  facet_wrap(~ supp)+
#  theme(
#    strip.background = element_blank(),
#    strip.text.x = element_blank())+
theme(plot.margin=unit(c(0,0,0,0),"cm"))+
scale_y_discrete(name ="Name")+
theme(text = element_text(size=11))+
theme(legend.position = "none")

a
```

[image: Plot]

Would be great if someone could see the problem; I'm going blind by now. Many thanks!!

Comment: As the variable mapped on y looks like a numeric: Try with `scale_y_continuous(name ="Name")` instead of `scale_y_discrete`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't your y axis be continuous?

```
scale_y_continuous(name ="Name")
```

Then you can add the limits and ticks positions as you want:

```
scale_y_continuous(name="Name",limits=c(min,max), breaks=c(a,b,c,d))
```

Comment: I'm ready to throw myself into a river because of shame....Thank you so much, of course that was it!!!